# Почтовый ящик читающий почту со всех остальных ящиков

Tags: веб-сервер, email

Есть почта на домене нашей организации.
Есть почтовые ящики различных отделов (секретарь, юр.отдел, бухгалтерия, директор и т.д.).

Нужно сделать так, чтобы ящик секретаря получал почту со всех других ящиков, при этом чтобы когда секретарь просматривал эти сообщения они помечались как прочитанные только у него (секретаря), а для всех остальных сотрудников оставались новыми (непрочитанными). Кроме того, если какой-либо сотрудник отправит письмо или же ответит на входящее, то секретарь должен это все тоже видеть (т.е. видеть все отправленные письма и все ответы в цепочках писем).

Как такое организовать?

Comment: Какие клиенты у юзеров и какой MTA?

Comment: клиенты: The Bat, MTA: Postfix

Comment: Не хотел бы я у вас работать.

Comment: нет, это не тотальный контроль за перепиской сотрудников, это скорее  невнимательность сотрудников всех остальных в плане обработки почты.

Comment: Пробуем пока использоваться Яндекс.Почту прикрепленную к нашему домену, однако даже при настройках сбора писем со всех ящиков на ящик секретаря, собираются только входящие письма.